# django test client: Django Restframework does not have PUT data from test client

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

Trying to write django unit tests for APIs with djangorestframeworks. But the api cannot get data from PUT method(request.data).

The api works just fine with form data from javascript and html but just cannot work with unit tests.

And the api works fine with POST method.

ps: request.body has correct data

tests.py:

```
    from django.test import TestCase, Client
    class TestAPI(TestCase):
    
      def setUp(self):
        '''all Set wtih Client(self.client) and User(self.user)
        ........'''
    
      def test_method(self):
        put_res = self.client.put('test_api/', data={'x': 3}, content_type="multipart/form-data")
        post_res = self.client.post('test_api/', data = {'x': 3},)
```

views.py

```
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    class Test(APIView):
      def put(self, request):
        print(request.data) # request.data is empty, but request.body is not. 
        return Response('wrong')
      
      def post(self, request):
        print(request.data) # got {'x': 3} correctly
        return Response('Good')
```

Comment: why are you sending `content_type` in `put` but not in `post`?

Comment: @VishalSingh since put is for updating in restful?

Comment: `content_type` has nothing to do with the method you're using. It tells you what type of data is actually sent. It can be used in POST and PUT but you're using it only on PUT. is there any specific reason?

Comment: @VishalSingh Because I noticed the default content_type for post() function is multipart/form-data but for put() it is application/octet-stream. And i need to send form-data from client so multipart/form-data is in use. ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.put

Comment: Ok. but did you try without `content_type`? let me know the results.

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes that was what I did at first. Without content_type it throws Exception: Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.